# How to handle large file upload to Google Bucket?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have the following Golang code to upload a file to Google bucket:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    "cloud.google.com/go/storage"
)

var serverPort = ":8444"
var googleCredential = "./credential.json"
var googleBucket = "g1-BUCKET-001"
var googleFolder = "test_folder/"

func uploadToBucket(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t1 := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("File Upload Endpoint Hit")

    // Parse our multipart form, 10 << 20 specifies a maximum
    // upload of 10 MB files.
    r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20)
    file, handler, err := r.FormFile("myFile")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, fmt.Sprintf("Error uploading file: %v", err))
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()
    fmt.Printf("Uploaded File: %+v\n", handler.Filename)
    fmt.Printf("File Size: %+v\n", handler.Size)
    fmt.Printf("MIME Header: %+v\n", handler.Header)

    // Upload file to bucket
    os.Setenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", googleCredential)
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, fmt.Sprintf("Error creating storage.NewClient: %v", err))
        return
    }
    defer client.Close()
    fmt.Println("Bucket client created.")

    // Set timeout
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second*7200)
    defer cancel()

    // Create bucket object for stream copy
    destFilePath := googleFolder + handler.Filename
    fmt.Printf("Target bucket: gs://" + googleBucket + "/.\n")
    fmt.Printf("Destination file path: " + destFilePath + ".\n")
    o := client.Bucket(googleBucket).Object(destFilePath)
    o = o.If(storage.Conditions{DoesNotExist: true})
    
    // Upload an object with storage.Writer.
    wc := o.NewWriter(ctx)
    if _, err = io.Copy(wc, file); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, fmt.Sprintf("io.Copy error: %v", err))
        return
    }
    if err := wc.Close(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, fmt.Sprintf("Writer.Close() error: %v", err))
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s uploaded to gs://%s/%s.", handler.Filename, googleBucket, googleFolder)

    t2 := time.Now()
    diff := t2.Sub(t1)
    fmt.Printf("Time start: %+v\n", t1)
    fmt.Printf("Time end: %+v\n", t2)
    fmt.Printf("Time diff: %+v\n", diff)

    // Return that we have successfully uploaded our file!
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Successfully Uploaded File\n")
}

func setupRoutes() {
    http.HandleFunc("/upload", uploadToBucket)
    http.ListenAndServe(serverPort, nil)
}

func main() {
    setupRoutes()
}
```

It works fine with file around 100MB.  However when it gets to 1GB+, the wait time is so long.  The user may think the code stops working and quit before it can finish.  For now, all they get is this line at the end:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "Successfully Uploaded File\n")
```

How can I implement a way to give the user some feedback, like a completion bar for instance?

Comment: Did you try a multipart upload?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, how can that be done?  Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option to add progress tracking to an arbitrary `io.Writer` such as you get from `o.NewWriter(ctx)`.  Using `io.MultiWriter` you can duplicate writes to multiple writers.  One can be your `o.NewWriter(ctx)` and another can be an implementation of `io.Writer` that simply counts bytes and can compare against a total size.

You could then run a goroutine that could periodically update progress by writing to stdout (or something else).

[Take a look at this example](https://go.dev/play/p/KdKUfjV43SW) using [This Proof of concept implementation](https://github.com/farrellit/writeprogress):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"

    "github.com/farrellit/writeprogress"
)

func main() {
    in, err := os.Open("/dev/urandom")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    out, err := os.OpenFile("/dev/null", os.O_WRONLY, 0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer in.Close()
    defer out.Close()

    length := int64(1e6)
    wp := writeprogress.NewProgressWriter(uint64(length))
    d, _ := wp.Watch(func(p float64) { fmt.Printf("\r%2.0f%%", p*100) })

    if b, err := io.Copy(
        io.MultiWriter(out, wp),
        &io.LimitedReader{R: in, N: length},
    ); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        <-d
        fmt.Printf("\n%d/%d %2.0f%%\n", b, length, wp.GetProgress()*100)
    }

}
```

You can do the same thing with your `o.NewWriter(ctx)` and a file length determined by `stat`.  you could also use it in conjunction with something like https://github.com/schollz/progressbar if you wanted something pretty.

Comment: This looks like a server-side solution.  How can I reflect the progress to the client side for the user to see the progress?

Comment: You can stream multipart answer and stream the progress like that. However, I don't know if the proposed answer is compliant with Cloud Storage.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, do you have an example that I can look at?  This is totally new to me.

Comment: Should work with cloud storage, because `NewWriter` return value satisfies `io.Writer`.  I've used it with MultiWriter before (not for progress tracking though)

Comment: @CaTx it's not server side or client side per se, it's go code.  But if it runs on the server end of a client, then yes, just like any other information the client sees, you'd have to send to the client.

Comment: @erik258, how can I send that to the client?  The file is being sent from a web UI, which is where I want to display the progress bar.

Comment: @CaTx I can't complete the multi part upload. The latest step, the "complete" does not work when there is more than 1 part. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-complete I will work with Google Cloud support and back to you when I have working code.

Comment: Ah, yeah I see your point.  You probably don't need to send it to the client at all: [this example](https://medium.com/swlh/uploading-files-with-progress-monitoring-in-vanillajs-angular-and-vuejs-625e2491821) (ingore the php part) uses some event handlers in javascript to track the file upload.

Comment: for that matter I'm not sure if doing a multi part upload on the go side is going to do you any better.   Even if the web client does multi part to the server I'm not sure how you're going to track that server side and then report to the client.  Looking into the javascript side of things sounds a lot more promising to me

Answer (score 0):

here a working example that stream the response after each part upload. Change your bucket, file source, the object target name and the content Type.

Curl the localhost:8080, you will received chunk response. Then, inject that logic in your code, with JSON response or whatever.

*My previous issue comes from the `chunkSize` below 5MiB in my tests.*

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

const (
    bucket      = "gib-multiregion-us"
    fileName    = "./20220909_ListePieces.csv"
    objectName  = "test-multipart.csv"
    contentType = "text/csv"

    // Min 5MiB with multiple of 256 KiB
    chunckSize = 5242880 + (256 * 1024 * 0)

    // API key values
    storageapi          = "storage.googleapis.com"
    uploadsExtension    = "uploads"
    partNumberExtension = "partNumber"
    uploadIdExtension   = "uploadId"
    etagKey             = "ETag"
)

var httpClient *http.Client

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    c, err := google.DefaultClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    httpClient = c

    http.HandleFunc("/", multipartUpload)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func multipartUpload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    url := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.%s/%s", bucket, storageapi, objectName)

    // init
    resp, err := httpClient.Post(fmt.Sprintf("%s?%s", url, uploadsExtension), contentType, nil)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Println("error during init: ", err)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "error during init: %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    respbody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Println("error during reading init resp: ", err)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "error during reading init resp: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    var initMultiPart InitiateMultipartUploadResult
    err = xml.Unmarshal(respbody, &initMultiPart)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Println("error during unmarshalling init resp: ", err)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "error during unmarshalling init resp: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    uploadId := initMultiPart.UploadId

    // send content
    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Println("error during reading input file: ", err)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "error during reading input file: %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Prepare the multipart response
    flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
    if !ok {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Println("Impossible to create the stream flusher: ", err)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Impossible to create the stream flusher: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked")
    flusher.Flush()

    complMulti := CompleteMultipartUpload{}
    counter := 0
    for {
        if len(content) <= counter*chunckSize {
            break
        }
        var toSend []byte
        if len(content) >= (counter+1)*chunckSize {
            toSend = content[counter*chunckSize : (counter+1)*chunckSize]
        } else {
            toSend = content[counter*chunckSize:]
        }
        req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPut, fmt.Sprintf("%s?%s=%d&%s=%s", url, partNumberExtension, counter+1, uploadIdExtension, uploadId), bytes.NewReader(toSend))
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            fmt.Println("error chunk req creation: ", err)
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "error chunk req creation: %s\n", err)
            return
        }
        resp, err = httpClient.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            fmt.Println("error chunk submission: ", err)
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "error chunk submission: %s\n", err)
            return
        }

        etag := resp.Header.Get(etagKey)
        p := Part{
            PartNumber: counter + 1,
            ETag:       etag,
        }

        fmt.Printf("upload is done at %d%%\n", 100*counter*chunckSize/len(content))

        fmt.Fprintf(w, "upload is done at %d%%\n", 100*counter*chunckSize/len(content))
        flusher.Flush()

        complMulti.Parts = append(complMulti.Parts, p)
        counter++
    }

    toSend, err := xml.Marshal(complMulti)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Println("error marshal complete multi: ", err)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "error marshal complete multi: %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Complete transfert
    resp, err = httpClient.Post(fmt.Sprintf("%s?%s=%s", url, uploadIdExtension, uploadId), "application/xml", bytes.NewReader(toSend))
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Println("error during send complete: ", err)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "error during send complete: %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    if resp.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "done")
        fmt.Println("done")
    } else {
        b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        fmt.Printf("error %s with body %s\n", resp.Status, string(b))
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "error %s with body %s\n", resp.Status, string(b))
    }

}

type InitiateMultipartUploadResult struct {
    InitiateMultipartUploadResult xml.Name `xml:"InitiateMultipartUploadResult"`
    Bucket                        string   `xml:"Bucket"`
    Key                           string   `xml:"Key"`
    UploadId                      string   `xml:"UploadId"`
}

type CompleteMultipartUpload struct {
    completeMultipartUpload xml.Name `xml:"CompleteMultipartUpload"`
    Parts                   []Part   `xml:"Part"`
}

type Part struct {
    part       xml.Name `xml:"Part"`
    PartNumber int      `xml:"PartNumber"`
    ETag       string   `xml:"ETag"`
}
```