# How to populate larger array of []byte from a smaller array of []byte in golang?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

So I'm downloading a file from an URL and splitting it into chunks with `content-range` header, and want to stream the download file into the progress bar. Currently I'm struggling when writing the downloaded bytes into the chunk. My approach is as follows:

```golang
type Chunk struct {
    response _http.Response
    wg       *sync.WaitGroup
    index    int
    start    int64
    end      int64
    size     int64
    data     []byte
    ctx      context.Context
}

func New(ctx context.Context, res _http.Response, index int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) *Chunk {
    totalpart := int64(res.Totalpart)
    partsize := res.Size / totalpart

    start := int64(index * int(partsize))
    end := start + int64(int(partsize)-1)

    if index == int(totalpart)-1 {
        end = res.Size
    }

    return &Chunk{
        response: res,
        wg:       wg,
        index:    index,
        start:    start,
        end:      end,
        size:     partsize,
        data:     make([]byte, partsize),
        ctx:      ctx,
    }
}

func (c *Chunk) download() error {
    defer c.wg.Done()

    http_ := &http.Client{}
    part := fmt.Sprintf("bytes=%d-%d", c.start, c.end)

    if c.size == -1 {
        log.Printf("Downloading chunk %d with size unknown", c.index+1)
    } else {
        log.Printf("Downloading chunk %d from %d to %d (~%d MB)", c.index+1, c.start, c.end, (len(c.data))/(1024*1024))
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", c.response.Url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    start := time.Now()

    req.Header.Add("Range", part)
    res, err := http_.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()

    var _100KB int64 = 1024 * 100
    buffer := make([]byte, _100KB)

    for {
        n, err := io.ReadFull(res.Body, buffer)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }

        //TODO: combine the downloaded bytes into c.data
        c.data = append(c.data, buffer[:n]...)
        runtime.EventsEmit(c.ctx, "transfered", c.index, n)
    }


    // c.data, err = io.ReadAll(res.Body)
    // if err != nil {
    //  return err
    // }

    // runtime.EventsEmit(c.ctx, "transfered", len(c.data))

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    log.Printf("Chunk %d downloaded in %v s\n", c.index+1, elapsed.Seconds())

    return nil
}
```

Whereas the `_http.Response` is my custom struct to fetch the data (such as total size of file, cansplit?, total part, and content type) of the URL before downloading it.

But there is a problem with the code above, which is the `len()` of `c.data` (the chunk data) became larger than the actual chunk size. For example, the chunk size of actual video file is 12 MB, but with the code above, the chunk became twice as big, and of course when when all chunks is combined into one video file, instead of taking 48 MB (for example), it's becoming 100 MB, and the downloaded video cannot be played.

In my attempt earlier, I was using `io.ReadAll(res.Body)` (code that I commented) and then write it into the `c.data`. After the downloading is done, the video file can be played, but not with the approach above. The drawback is, I can't stream the download because I need to download it entirely

If I was going to log the `len()` of the file before and after downloading the chunk, the the `len()` after the download process would become 2x larger.

I thought the spread operator with append is enough to populate each element of the `c.data` from beginning to end. And I think, because it's using `append`, it doesn't matter if the data is exceeding the `len()` from the array initiation. Anyone know the issue? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: "want to stream the download file into the progress bar.  The method how to download is by splitting the file with content-range header and then download it in chunks"  Sounds like an X Y problem.  You started with wanting to stream the download to the progress bar.  Now you're trying to stitch together chunks.   If the response body is *actually* streamable (web requests are), and the progress bar supports streaming, you can do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75949860/how-to-handle-large-file-upload-to-google-bucket/75952067#75952067) to connect them

Comment: We don't see `c.data`. My guess, it's created with a too large sitze and when you append something, you append it behind the "empty" but reserved entries. So, let c.Data be something like `[1,2,3,0,0,0]` with the last three bytes being the "empty" ones b/c you've created it with a size of 6, after appending you'll have something like `[1,2,3,0,0,0,4,5,6]`. How's `c.data` being created? Additionally, make sure to check that if `n` is < 100 KB to truncate the slice accordingly before appending it - this is likely to happen in the last round.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the server responds with a partial content response.

Here are some fixes to the loop which I assume is run on each response: Append the reported number of bytes to the buffer. Break after copying any data read to c.data. Break on any error.

```
for {
    n, err := io.ReadFull(res.Body, buffer)
    c.data = append(c.data, buffer[:n]...)
    if err != nil {
        break
    }

    runtime.EventsEmit(c.ctx, "transfered", c.index, n)
}
```

There's no need to use content-range to report progress.  Request the entire resource and report bytes read as in the loop above.

Comment: Tried this before with `buffer[:n]` but it's still doubled the size. The `error != nil` is the same. It's strange, I've tested this before with simple hello world with the same approach, but the hellow world is from `strings.NewReader("hello world")`, and it works fine. But this...

Comment: `There's no need to use content-range to report progress`, the content-range is not to report progress, it's just to download the file into chunks. The code I provided above is to download the chunk. As you can see, the buffer is just 100kb, the progress is updated every 100kb donwloaded

Comment: @newtocoding Did you ensure that the server is returning a partial content response?

Comment: I think so, because when I'm using `io.ReadAll(res.body)` it is downloading the chunk that I want. How do I know? I check if the `len()` of `c.data` is the same as `partsize`, and it is the same. When I combine the chunks into one file, it plays the video correctly. But not with my current approach. Btw, I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.

It turns out, the `append` is literally appending to the next element after index of `partsize`. I tried to reassign the `c.data` after the download process with

```golang
var _100KB int64 = 1024 * 100
buffer := make([]byte, _100KB)
transfered := 0

for {
    n, err := io.ReadFull(res.Body, buffer)
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    transfered += n
    //TODO: combine the downloaded bytes into c.data
    c.data = append(c.data, buffer[:n]...)
    runtime.EventsEmit(c.ctx, "transfered", c.index, n)
}

c.data = c.data[transfered:]
```

And it works now. The downloaded video file is playable

But, after some further research, I could just make the slice with `cap`, so I need to initiate the slice with the following code to make it even simpler, and I don't need to slice the array after the download process finished

```golang
func New(ctx context.Context, res _http.Response, index int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) *Chunk {
    //...

    return &Chunk{
        //...
        data:     make([]byte, 0, partsize),
        //...
    }
}
```